# Adding an image to my email script using Google Sheets

Tags: image, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that links an image I created and saved in my google drive to a specific score achieved by a person. I want to email that image along with a subject and a generic statement to them. This is the current script I have. var currentBadge is the label I gave for the image that my sheet pulls up.

```
  function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  var numColms = 5; // Number of columns to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColms);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0]; // First column;
    var emailAddress = row[1] // Second column;
    var subject = row[2]; // Third column;
    var message = row[3]; // Fourth column;
    var currentBadge = row[4]; // Fifth column;
    message=message.replace("<name>",name).replace("<currentBadge>", currentBadge);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message)}
  }
```

I need help with the rest of this please, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: "var currentBadge is the label I gave for the image that my sheet pulls up" is this a URL of the image?

Comment: It shows the image on the cell but it is from a URL that has been published in my google drive

Comment: So what is the issue you are having ?. Please see [how-do-i-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)